# Dynamic tooltip update leaflet

Tags: leaflet

How can I make my tooltips update when I change years on this map?

http://argis.ualr-iea.org/dash_new_design/uninsured_map.html

Using the select box, I can get the style to change but I can't figure out how to update the numbers in the tooltip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `setToolTipContent()` method.  See the documentation [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tooltip) (it's hidden in the expandable part of the documentation "Tooltip methods inherited from Layer")

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but if you are wondering why [the accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262030/107424) doesn't work, it's because the correct function name is `setTooltipContent()`, where **t**ip is not capitalised.